# Handling Security Errors in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, api, error-handling, vimeo

I am using an imported class for a vimeo player in AS3, it is the official vimeo player api (vimeo.com). I want to handle any Security Errors that an instance of the class throws (they get thrown when the obect fails to load an external URL for a video). This is what I have got:

```
    var clipPlayer = new VimeoPlayer("5d22d3942a54d7c75b931bab4a911857", videoID[clickedClip], fullVideoWidth, fullVideoHeight, "10", 2);
    clipPlayer.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR , vimeoError);
```

Later in the code ofcourse, I've got the function that handles the event:

```
    function vimeoError (e : SecurityErrorEvent) : void {
        trace("vimeo player failed to load");
    }
```

This all seems straight forward, but yet the Error Handler is not firing. I must be missing something here... Maybe you can't register this kind of event listener on a VimeoPlayer object. However, I am pretty certain it is the VimeoPlayer object throwing them. Here is an example of what I am getting:

```
Error opening URL 
'http://api.vimeo.com/moogaloop_api.swf?oauth_key=5d22d3942a54d7c75b931bab4a911857&clip_id=21185860&width=500&height=281&fullscreen=0&fp_version=10&api=1&cache_buster=565.7249609939754'
SecurityError: Error #2000: No active security context.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dispatched error *events* are separate from thrown `Error`s. In many cases both kinds can occur, and then you need to listen for the former *and* catch the latter with a `try` statement around the code that may throw. The error you quote seems to be of the thrown variety (as events typically stringize to something involving square brackets).

Comment: It would be strange if it were a thrown error. It seems to me that it would have to be asynchronous, because it would have to run through its own code in its class to try to load the URL, this wouldn;t be instantaneous. Tell me if I;m wrong, because I don't fully understand how errors work in AS3

Comment: Thrown errors can be asynchronous in the following, rather unpleasant, sense: It is possible that the VimeoPlayer implementation registers an internal event handler, and something done by that handler causes a thrown Error and neglects to catch it. In that case there is noting you can do to catch the error directly. Supposedly (and this is really beyond the limits of my own AS3 fu) you can get at it by registering an `uncauchtError` handler in `LoaderInfo.uncaughtErrorEvents` -- but that will give you _everything_, with no easy way to distinguish that particular SecurityError.

Comment: Hmmm..... the last method you just described might work in my situation, if I can figure it out.  If I were just able to distinguish SecurityErrors from those that aren't, then I could have a single action be performed whenever any load error occured. I'll look in to this.

Comment: Tried uncaughtError tactic and got all of my load errors to fire what I needed! this is even better than whaat I wanted before, because I don't have to register every urlloader for a security error!